# How to return the date in which my JSP has been created

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to make a simple web application in which my jsp gets as a parameter a `username` and writes the following message:

"Hello `username`, you are our `xxx` visitor since `date`"

Thus, I've written this `index.html` page:

```
<body>    
    <form action="myjsp.jsp" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="Submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>
</body>
```

and the JSP:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%!
            int hitCounter = 0;
        %>

        <p>
            Hello <%= request.getParameter("username") %> you are our <%= (++hitCounter) %> visitor since <%= new Date() %>
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the output:

[image: output]

everything is ok except for the date: as I refresh or "re-boot" my web application, the date gets updated (probably because I've written `new Date()` in that expression and so the date gets update on every request).

- How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
make a declaration as follows:

```
<%! Date date = new Date() %>
```

and `replace <%= new Date() %>` 
with

```
<%= date %>
```